# Load slide-up box content only when scroll is triggered

Tags: jquery, wordpress, pagespeed, pingdom

I have a facebook likebox slide up . It slides up when 75% of the page is scrolled. I want the slide-up to load the likebox only when its triggered. But it loads the likebox in the background even if its not triggered (as per the pingdom tools test). Is there a way to avoid loading of the likebox when its not triggered ?

Website : [thegeekdiary.com](http://thegeekdiary.com)

Plugin used to create slide-up : [scroll triggered boxes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/scroll-triggered-boxes/)

Comment: are you saying that you dont want the box appears when scrolling the page but with another event (like clicking a button or something)?

Comment: No. I want when i scroll 75% of my webpage, then the likebox starts to load in the slideup not before that. as per pingdom tool I see facebook requests being made (assuming the pingdom test does not scroll the page)

Comment: so, it just appears when one has scrolled the whole page but you want that it appears when the page has been scrolled 75% if I got it right. Do you have access to the source code? You might post it here and I'll be able to help you.

Comment: here's the github : https://github.com/dannyvankooten/scroll-triggered-boxes-for-wordpress

Comment: It looks like is perfectly customizable when the box should display. Just open the plugin url: https://wordpress.org/plugins/scroll-triggered-boxes/ .... and click the tab: screenshots. Check there the last image. Regards.